# How do I change color of clear button in TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We're using the  component for a search field. When entering something into the field an "x" clear button appears. I can't figure out how to change the color of this button. We're not using an icon button or anything like that, and if I try to inspect the clear button it I can't find it in the dom, only the input field is shown selected.

I've understood that the normal approach to adding a clear button is to use inputAdornment. We are using inputAdornment for a progress indicator, but I can't find anything in our code for the clear button, so wondering if this is something default and how to go about changing it, or at least get a reference to it so I can use css to style it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: You can use IconButton Component after your textfield and apply custom class to it, also you can add onclick events on it.. use display: flex property to make the textfield and clear icon inline.. You can also hide it using some state variable, only when you type the text make the clear icon visible.